# loader is not working when I am clicking submit button

Tags: java, jsp

loader is not working when I am clicking submit button  on Register page. I hava added Thread.sleep(3000; in Register.java page
`
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("Page is ready...... ") ;
$("#myform").on('submit',function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var f = $(this).serialize();
console.log(f);
$(".loader").show();
$(".form").hide();

```
                $.ajax({
                   url:"Register",
                   data:f,
                   type:'POST',
                   success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
                       console.log(data);
                       console.log("Success......");
                       $(".loader").hide();
                       $(".form").show();
                       if(data.trim()==="Done"){
                           $("#msg").html("Succesfully Registered !!!");
                           $("#msg").addClass("green-text");
                       }else{
                           $("#msg").html("Something went wrong !!!");
                           $("#msg").addClass("red-text");
                       }
                       
                   },
                   error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
                       console.log(data);
                       console.log("error");
                       $(".loader").hide();
                       $(".form").show();
                       $("#msg").html("Something went wrong !!!");
                       $("#msg").addClass("red-text");
                   }
               });   
            });
            });`
```

```
package com.user;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            /*out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Register</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");*/
            //Getting all the details from incoming from request
            String name=request.getParameter("user_name");
            String email=request.getParameter("user_email");
            String password=request.getParameter("user_password");
            //out.println(name);
            //out.println(email);
            //out.println(password);
            //connection
             try{
                 Thread.sleep(3000);
                 Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                 Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/youtube1","root","Vandana");
                 
                 //query
                 String q="insert into user(name,email,password) value(?, ?, ?)";
                 PreparedStatement pstmpt= con.prepareStatement(q);
                 pstmpt.setString(1, name);
                 pstmpt.setString(2, password);
                 pstmpt.setString(3, email);
            
                 
                 pstmpt.executeUpdate();
                 
                 out.println("Done");
             } 
             
             catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace() ;
                out.println("Error");
             }

            
            
            //......
            //out.println("</body>");
            //out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

````
    Document   : signup
    Created on : 01-Feb-2022, 2:13:08 PM
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
            
    </head>
    <body style="background-image: url(images/bg.jpg); background-size: cover;background-attachment: fixed;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col m6 offset-m3">
                    
                    <div class="card">
                         <div class="card-content">
                             <div class="form center-align">
                                 <h3 style="margin-top: 10px;"class="center-align">Register Here !!</h3>
                                 <h5 id="msg" class="center-align"</h5>
                                <div class="form">
                                <!-- creating form -->
                                <form action="Register" method="post" id="myform">
                                    <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Enter user_name"\>
                                    <input type="password" name="user_password" placeholder="Enter password"\>
                                    <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Enter your email"\>
                                    
                                    <button type="submit" name="btn" style="background-color:#b3e5fc;">Submit</button>
                                    
                                </form>
                                <div class="loader center-align" style="margin-top: 10px; display: none;" >
                                        <div class="preloader-wrapper big active">
                                            <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
                                              <div class="circle-clipper left">
                                                <div class="circle"></div>
                                              </div><div class="gap-patch">
                                                <div class="circle"></div>
                                              </div><div class="circle-clipper right">
                                                <div class="circle"></div>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                            
                                    <h5>Please Wait....</h5>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
                
        </script>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log("Page is ready...... ") ;
                $("#myform").on('submit',function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var f = $(this).serialize();
                console.log(f);
                $(".loader").show();
                $(".form").hide();
                     
                    $.ajax({
                       url:"Register",
                       data:f,
                       type:'POST',
                       success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
                           console.log(data);
                           console.log("Success......");
                           $(".loader").hide();
                           $(".form").show();
                           if(data.trim()==="Done"){
                               $("#msg").html("Succesfully Registered !!!");
                               $("#msg").addClass("green-text");
                           }else{
                               $("#msg").html("Something went wrong !!!");
                               $("#msg").addClass("red-text");
                           }
                           
                       },
                       error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
                           console.log(data);
                           console.log("error");
                           $(".loader").hide();
                           $(".form").show();
                           $("#msg").html("Something went wrong !!!");
                           $("#msg").addClass("red-text");
                       }
                   });   
                });
                });
       
        </script>
    </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Could you please use javascript/jquery tags as well? Also, it would be nice to indent the code block better. When you say loader is not working, do you mean the response is coming too quickly? - in which case it's a Java issue and we need to see some Java code. Otherwise, if the response takes time but the loader does not appear, it is a JS issue. It would be better to add HTML of the loader too if you think it could be relevant.

Comment: I am new here don't know how to add code properly here so please wait  I am trying to add code here

Comment: No problem. Just trying to help you make the question better.

Comment: I added Register.java and signup.jsp code please help why my loader is not working when  I press submit button also form do not appear it shows only green registered successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the HTML.

You need to move the loader outside this div to make it work.

```html
<div class="form center-align">
```

Otherwise, when you call `$(".form").hide();`, everything inside this div will be hidden, including the loader.

Comment: This is already outside <div class="form center-align">